# How define an array of function pointers in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function-pointers

I've a little question.
I'm trying to define an array of function pointers dynamically with `calloc`. 
But I don't know how to write the syntax.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show us what you wrote until now?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The type of a function pointer is just like the function declaration, but with "(*)" in place of the function name.  So a pointer to:

```
int foo( int )
```

would be:

```
int (*)( int )
```

In order to name an instance of this type, put the name inside (*), after the star, so:

```
int (*foo_ptr)( int )
```

declares a variable called foo_ptr that points to a function of this type.

Arrays follow the normal C syntax of putting the brackets near the variable's identifier, so:

```
int (*foo_ptr_array[2])( int )
```

declares a variable called foo_ptr_array which is an array of 2 function pointers.

The syntax can get pretty messy, so it's often easier to make a typedef to the function pointer and then declare an array of those instead:

```
typedef int (*foo_ptr_t)( int );
foo_ptr_t foo_ptr_array[2];
```

In either sample you can do things like:

```
int f1( int );
int f2( int );
foo_ptr_array[0] = f1;
foo_ptr_array[1] = f2;
foo_ptr_array[0]( 1 );
```

Finally, you can dynamically allocate an array with either of:

```
int (**a1)( int ) = calloc( 2, sizeof( int (*)( int ) ) );
foo_ptr_t * a2 = calloc( 2, sizeof( foo_ptr_t ) );
```

Notice the extra * in the first line to declare a1 as a pointer to the function pointer.

Comment: I tried your last example and it works but, what about casting `calloc` result? is it not necessary? eg: `int (**a1)( int ) = (some_casting) calloc( 2, sizeof( int (*)( int ) ) );`

Comment: @auraham The cast is not necessary in C. The `void *` type will implicitly convert to any other pointer-to-object type.

Comment: typedef int (*foo_ptr_t)( int ); shouldn't be this as following:

typedef int (*foo_ptr_t)( int ) foo_ptr_t; 

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 5):

I put a small example here that may help you

```
typedef void (*fp)(int); //Declares a type of a void function that accepts an int

void test(int i)
{
    printf("%d", i);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    fp function_array[10];  //declares the array

    function_array[0] = test;  //assings a function that implements that signature in the first position

    function_array[0](10); //call the cuntion passing 10

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'd declare an array of function pointers as

```
T (*afp[N])();
```

for some type `T`.  Since you're dynamically allocating the array, you'd do something like

```
T (**pfp)() = calloc(num_elements, sizeof *pfp);
```

or

```
T (**pfp)() = malloc(num_elements * sizeof *pfp);
```

You'd then call each function as

```
T x = (*pfp[i])();
```

or

```
T x = pfp[i](); // pfp[i] is implicitly dereferenced
```

If you want to be unorthodox, you can declare a pointer to an array of pointers to functions, and then allocate that as follows:

```
T (*(*pafp)[N])() = malloc(sizeof *pafp);
```

although you would have to deference the array pointer when making the call:

```
x = (*(*pafp)[i])();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your functions are of type `void ()(void)`, something like this

```
typedef void (*fxptr)(void);
fxptr *ptr; // pointer to function pointer
ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof *ptr);
if (ptr) {
    ptr[0] = fx0;
    ptr[1] = fx1;
    /* ... */
    ptr[99] = fx100;

    /* use "dynamic array" of function pointers */

    free(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef R (*fptr)(A1, A2... An);
```

where R is the return type, A1, A2... An are the argument types.

```
fptr* arr = calloc(num_of_elements,sizeof(fptr));
```