# C Dynamic Array of Function Pointers, with Dynamically Specified Parameters

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am using a system that allows me to attach callbacks on events. At compile time I do not know how many of these or what type they will be. 
Since there are no parameters possible for these callbacks and I need them all to end up being handled by the same code I need some ID for each callback. I am programming in C.

I have seen a number of related questions, but none quite manage what I am trying to achieve. This 
solution for instance gives instructions for dynamically creating an array of function pointers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5488718/2207774

To demonstrate the functionality I am looking for below is code which works at the moment. I am trying to replace this code with something dynamic since I am currently needing to guess the maximum possible attachments I will need:

```
static void event_handler(int eventID);

static void int_0(void){event_handler(0);};
static void int_1(void){event_handler(1);};
static void int_2(void){event_handler(2);};
static void int_3(void){event_handler(3);};

static void (*interrupt_handlers[4])(void) = {int_0,int_1,int_2,int_3};
```

Then to attach each to the required event:

```
api_call_register_event(SOME_EXTERNAL_ID, interrupt_handlers[eventID++]);
```

What I would like to do:

```
static void (*int_n)(int);
void (**interrupt_handlers)( int );
```

Then in my code I would like to be able to set this up:

```
int number_required = 10;
interrupt_handlers = malloc(number_required, sizeof( void (*)( int ) ) );
```

Then to attach each to the required event (NOTE THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK, int_n(eventID) WILL EVALUATE THE FUNCTION):

```
interrupt_handlers[eventID] = int_n(eventID);
api_call_register_event(SOME_EXTERNAL_ID, interrupt_handlers[eventID++]);
```

If there is a different way to do this please let me know, of any suggestions about easing this implementation. It would be really nice if I could pass a value as a parameter to a function while it is still a pointer. Another possibility that has occurred to me to to have a structure for function pointers and a parallel one for the eventID, this seems clumsy.

Comment: So you do **not** know all possible function signatures (permutations of return types and number and types and order of parameters) in advance, right?

Comment: I am happy to have just a single integer parameter and a void return. What I don't know is the number of function handles I will need. I also don't know what the EventID will be for each. In the code above I have shown EventID incrementing, this is not actually the case I just wanted to show that they are different values, Consider it to be any number less than the number of possible events.

Comment: Your approach creating the array looks ok. What exactly does not work. In terms of calling, you can tread a function pointer like a function. What's `int_n` for? Where do you assign a value to the latter?

Comment: @alk I can only pass a function of the form **void foo (void)** to the callback API. I need all of these events to call my event_handler method with an **int ID**. The functions **int_n** bridge this gap by allowing me to have an array of (void) methods which call event_handler with the correct ID. This is what I want to be able to specify at run time. 
Another way to express this is I want:
**interrupt_handlers[eventID] = {event_handler(eventID);};**
So I want an entry into interrupt_handlers to be a function which calls event_handler with the eventID.

Comment: I do not see a way to change the number of interrupt-handlers during runtime, as when the handler is called it does not know from which index of the handler-array it origins. So the array-index (that is the event-id) needs be hardcode into the handler.

Comment: @alk I waited a few days to see if someone would have a better suggestion. If you post the solution telling me 'You cannot do this' then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a way to change the number of interrupt-handlers during runtime, as when the handler is called it does not know from which index of the handler-array it origins. So the array-index (that is the event-id) needs be hardcode into the handler.

However, you might start to think about generating C sources by some external tool and add this to the program build process.