# Malloc an array of function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers

I have an array of functions that needs to be allocated at run-time to be called in sequence. Which function pointer goes in which spot is determined programatically, e.g.:

```
void ((drawFunctions*)(...))[0] = drawTriangle;
...
for(...)
    drawFunctions[i](...);
```

I want to malloc an array of function pointers because I don't know until run-time how many will be needed. How would you do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488608/how-define-an-array-of-function-pointers-in-c

Comment: Do all the functions take the same parameters? Does the "..." indicated omitted code or is it literally "..." to indicate they're variadic?

Comment: You'll better edit your question to have real C99 code and avoid your `...`

Comment: To my knowledge, the only thing an ellipsis means is "fill in the blank with something that makes sense". The ellipsis summarizes stuff that isn't relevant to the question and would just take up space.

Comment: Variadic functions, huh? Interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A typedef would probably make the syntax a little more bearable:

```
typedef void (*drawFunctionPointer)(void);
drawFunctionPointer *drawFunctions = malloc(sizeof(drawFunctionPointer) * numFunctions);
```

Comment: OK, now how to initialize this pointer ?

I tried this but I get a warning.

`FPTR *cr1_task_fptr = malloc(CR1_TASKS*sizeof(FPTR));
    (cr1_task_fptr) = (FPTR){&function1, &function2, &function3, &function4};` it says: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer

Answer (score 3):

First, in C99, a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) should have at least one first non-variadic argument (like `printf` has a `const char*fmt` first argument). See [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html)

Then, for readability purposes, I would use a `typedef` to declare the function signature, e.g.

```
 typedef void drawfun_sigt (int, ...);
```

Declare a variable holding the pointer to an array of pointers:

```
 drawfun_sigt** parr = NULL;
```

Allocate it (and handle failure):

```
 size_t nbfun = somenumber();
 parr = malloc(nbfun*sizeof(drawfun_sigt*));
 if (!parr) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Clear it (to make the behavior more reproducible, I dislike uninitialized elements in `malloc`-ed arrays; but [cmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445184/cmaster) commented that [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) would find these bugs); you could have used `calloc` instead of `malloc`:

```
 memset (parr, 0, nbfun*sizeof(drawfun_sigt*));
```

then fill it appropriately

```
 extern void drawfunfoo(int, ....);
 parr[0] = drawfunfoo;
```

Of course, there are many ways to get a function address. On POSIX systems (notably Linux) you can even get such an address *dynamically* by its name using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

If your function pointers have a completely unknown signature (i.e. if the ellipsis `...` meant something else than variadic function in your question), you should use [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) (or, if the set of signature is known, use a `union` of function pointers). Be aware that the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (and the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) on your C implementation may (and often does) dictate different ways to call functions with different signature. For example the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) for Linux requires variadic functions and non-variadic functions to be called differently, and passes some formal arguments in registers (different registers for integer and for floating point).

Comment: Any reason not to use `calloc` if you're going to zero it  right after malloc?

Comment: Because the OP wants `malloc`. Indeed I prefer `calloc`

Comment: Zeroing out memory after `malloc` seems pretty pointless to me *unless you actually use those zeros*. Reading parts of an allocation that you have not written to is always an error, and ensuring that you only have zeros to read may only serve to mask the error. More importantly: If you use zero'ed memory allocations *`valgrind` won't find those errors anymore*. Without the zeroing, it will report use of uninitialized data. With zeroing, `valgrind` sees that you actively initialize the memory before reading, so it won't ring the alarm. So, `calloc()` is really contraproductive in avoiding bugs.

Comment: real programmers don't use valgrind :))))))))) (just kidding)