# Making an array of function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

My problem is: I want to write a program which create an array function pointers. I know how to make pointer to function, but don't know how to make array of them.

This is what I tried up to now:

```
double add(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
double sub(double a, double b) { return a - b; }
double mult(double a, double b) { return a * b; }
double div(double a, double b) { return a/b; }

int main() {
    double(*Padd)(double a, double b);
    double(*Psub)(double a, double b);
    double(*Pmult)(double a, double b);
    double(*Pdiv)(double a, double b);

    Padd = &add;
    Psub = &sub;
    Pmult = &mult;
    Pdiv = &div;
}
```

In my code I create these pointers to functions in an array like e.g.

```
double Tpointers[3];
Tpointers[0] = Padd;
Tpointers[1] = Psub;
Tpointers[2] = Pmult;
Tpointers[3] = Pdiv;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What is this `indicator board` supposed to do? Your question is needs alot more explaining. Preferably by an example in code.

Comment: What is an "indicator board"? Please use the correct English translation.

Comment: Array pointers.

Comment: Check out [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). But the bigger question is: *Why do you want to do this?*. What do you want to reach in the end?

Comment: I think you are trying to create array of function pointers, please have a look at **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488608/how-define-an-array-of-function-pointers-in-c** it has answer for it

Comment: Vasanth Alagiriswamy it's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank's a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare a new type 'Tpointers' that represent a pointer to a function that give two double and return a double.

And in the code you can create an array of functions.

```
#include<iostream>

// The function pointer type!
typedef double (*Tpointers)(double, double);

double add(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
double sub(double a, double b) { return a - b; }
double mult(double a, double b) { return a * b; }
double div(double a, double b) { return a / b; }

int main() {
  // A functions pointers array .
  Tpointers fun_array[4];

  // Assign the values 
  fun_array[0] = &add;
  fun_array[1] = &sub;
  fun_array[2] = &mult;
  fun_array[3] = &div;

  // A little test
  std::cout << fun_array[2](3, 3) << " " << fun_array[3](3,3) << " " << fun_array[1](3,3)
        << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In c++ you can also create an std::vector of functions pointer ... or any containers from the std libraries of "Tpointers".